# How to open new incognito window in selenium python

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How I can open new incognito window? I mean when an iteration will be finished I want to open new incognito window:

```
class JoinPage(unittest.TestCase):

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    cls.browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/andrew/Downloads/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)

def test_01_new_account_jp(self):
    with open('/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/test/jpage/accounts.csv', 'rb', ) as csvfile:
        the_file = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in the_file:
            for i in range(2):
                self.browser.get('http://localhost:5000')
                user = row[0]
                password = row[1]
                self.browser.xpath('html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/button').click()
                self.browser.xpath(".//*[@id='Email']").send_keys(user)
                self.browser.xpath(".//*[@id='next']").click()
                self.browser.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']").send_keys(password)
```

But when I write my code like this:

```
class JoinPage(unittest.TestCase):


def test_01_new_account_jp(self):
    with open('/home/andrey/PycharmProjects/test/jpage/accounts.csv', 'rb', ) as csvfile:
        the_file = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in the_file:
            chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()  
            chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito') 
            chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')  
            browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/andrey/Downloads/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options) 
            actions = ActionChains(browser)
            wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
            browser.implicitly_wait(30)
            browser.get('http://localhost:5000')
            user = row[0]
            password = row[1]
            browser.xpath('html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/button').click()
            browser.xpath(".//*[@id='Email']").send_keys(user)
            browser.xpath(".//*[@id='next']").click()
            browser.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']").send_keys(password)
```

Work. I know this is not right to write like this.

Comment: Are you saying it's not currently opening incognito when you try the above?

Comment: When  the code start new iteration I need new incognito window.

Comment: OK, so what currently happens?

Comment: Nothing... that's the problem... I try to send keys to browser Ctrl+Shift+N but nothing happen

Comment: So on the first run of your test it opens incognito, on the second iteration it opens the normal browser?

Comment: No, on the second iteration, it opens browser, and he save session that I don't need

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code for commonly used browsers. Hope this helps.

- Chrome:

  ```
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("incognito");
  capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
  ```
- FireFox:

  ```
  FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();    
  firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", true);
  ```
- Internet Explorer:

  ```
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
  capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS, true); 
  capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_SWITCHES, "-private");
  ```
- Opera:

  ```
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.operaBlink();
  OperaOptions options = new OperaOptions();
  options.addArguments("private");
  capabilities.setCapability(OperaOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
  ```